# Can I change the ordering for grouped dock items to be static?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

In the Ubuntu dock on Ubuntu 18.04, multiple windows of the same application are grouped and orange dots are shown to tell you how many windows of the application are opened. When you click on the icon, a small screen capture of each of the windows is shown.

However, these screen captures are shown in an order that's based on which window was last active on the desktop. This is something that clashes with the way I use the dock. I'm used to mentally mapping the windows to their dock positions. As such, I will often be trying to get to "the top one" and then I end up needing several clicks before I actually get to the terminal (or some other application) that I was looking for.

Is there some way to make sure that the order of these screen captures does not change whenever a window becomes active?